Send MediaRecorder audio chunks with Websockets
I'm trying to send audio chunks recorded with MediaRecorder to the server and then to another client using Websockets and play it there.
The first chunk gets played normally but then I get

Error decoding audio data: EncodingError: Failed to execute 'decodeAudioData' on 'BaseAudioContext': Unable to decode audio data`

This is my code:
Recording:
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
  mimeType: "audio/webm",
});

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = async (event) => {
  if (event.data.size > 0) {
    const b64 = await blobToBase64(event.data);
    sendMessage({
      payload: {
        base64: b64,
      },
    });
  }
};

mediaRecorder.start(250);

Playing:
const arrayBuffer = base64ToArrayBuffer(message.payload.base64);
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const audioBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
const source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = audioBuffer;
source.connect(audioContext.destination);
source.start();

Helper functions:
const base64ToArrayBuffer = (base64: string): ArrayBuffer => {
  const binaryString = window.atob(base64);
  const len = binaryString.length;
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes.buffer;
};

const blobToBase64 = (blob: Blob): Promise<string> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
    reader.onerror = reject;
  });
};


Not sure if relevant, but the MDN docs on FileReader:readAsDataURL() state that the Base64 string cannot be directly decoded without removing data:*/*;base64 first from the string. Is that possibly the reason for your error?

Good catch, but no, didn't help.

Too bad, would be an easy fix. Alternatively I see that the WebSockets::send method supports sending a Blob or ArrayBuffer directly without having to encode it. Or is that a limitation you're working around?

'This method only works on complete file data, not fragments of audio file data.'
This is phrase I red in this link   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData            hope this will help you

